# Valid URL in sitemap

Tags: xml, url, sitemap

Which of this is a valid URL/URI in a sitemap ?

`www.site.com?id=5&token=10`
`www.site.com?id=5&amp;token=10`

Answer (score 1):

If it is a normal Link href="www.site.com?id=5&token=10" is correct.

Comment: &amp; is HTML encoding, not URL encoding.

Comment: When inserting `&` in URL for Sitemap XML through PHP it shows error, and script halts at that point :(

Answer (score 1):

You should use

```
&amp;
```

instead &.

Here is the part of official doc:

> Entity escaping
>
> Your Sitemap file must be UTF-8 encoded (you can generally do this when you save the file).
>
> As with all XML files, any data values (including URLs) must use entity escape codes for the
>
> characters listed in the table below.

```
    Character    Escape Code
    Ampersand    &  &amp;
    Single Quote     '  &apos;
    Double Quote     "  &quot;
    Greater Than     >  &gt;
    Less Than    <  &lt;
```